# Unable to make Rest call for SSL certificate(https) site

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I built Springboot micro services application, here i am making rest call to other website which was SSL certificate protected, i imported certificate to my java keystore and i am able to make rest call and able to get response when i am debugging that application from eclipse IDE, but when i am trying to run the jar from command prompt using the command **java -jar xxx.jar** then application starts and run time unable to get response from the same site. I have configured JAVA_HOME environment variable in my system and using the same jre for Eclipse and command prompt , i have no clue what caused this issue. Any one help me identifying root cause.
Thanks

Comment: Here the problem was i installed JRE to program files after moved to other folder, even though i set java home to the folder to which i moved from cmd it was taking jre config files from program files only.

Comment: Issue with folder name Program Files (X86) installed to different folder and set JAVA_HOME to the installed folder and imported certificate resolved issue.